# различие между for и while в js

Tags: javascript, frontend

Недавно проходил собеседование на Fronted разраба, спросили разницу между for и while, не смог ответить. Если можно сделать все, то что делается на while, можно сделать на for и даже больше. Так в чем разница?

Comment: Разница хотя бы в том, что оператор `for` позволяет объявить в себе переменные :) То есть, `for (здесь; ....; ....)`. Вообще, `for` часто называют циклом со счетчиком (хотя в JS это не всегда верно), тогда как `while` чисто условный.

Comment: Разница в удобстве для разных задач. А то так можно докатиться до того, что оба не нужны и можно всё на `if` и `go to` сделать.

Comment: С появлением `let/const` существенная разница в области видимости служебных переменных (счетчика, например). А с `var`, по-моему, разница чисто синтактическая, c `for` все объявления и приращения в одном блоке (в скобках), а с `while` служебная переменная будет вне блока, приращение в теле блока, условие в скобках.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, можно, но в js нет goto